# Plotly Python image when written using fig.write_image('image.svg') is not waiting for annotations to load

Tags: python, maps, gis, plotly-python

I am using plotly in python to create maps using mapbox. There's 'Annotations' in my map that I make using scattermapbox in text mode. But since my map is a little bit heavy, when i write an image with plolty's default way, it doesn't wait for that text to show and only shows the base polygons.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(pldf, 
                           geojson=pldf.geometry, 
                           locations=pldf.index, 
                           #color='region',
                           color="sa1",
                           #color_continuous_scale="Cividis_r",
                           #color_discrete_map=category_colors,
                           color_discrete_map={r.sa1:r.weighted_colour for i, r in pldf[pldf.weighted_colour.notnull()].iterrows()},
                           title=f"Ethnic Diversity ({sal})",
                           #mapbox_style="light",
                           #mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           center={"lat": y_center, "lon": x_center},
                           zoom=custom_zoom-0.2,
                           opacity=0.5,
                          )
fig.update_layout(legend_title_text='Ethnicity')
for trace in fig.data:
    trace.showlegend = False

boundary_lats = [a[1] for a in sal_exterior]
boundary_lons = [a[0] for a in sal_exterior]

# Add boundary as a line on the map
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=boundary_lats,
        lon=boundary_lons,
        mode='lines',
        line=dict(width=5, color='#6495ED'),  # Customize the line properties
        name='Suburb Boundary',
        showlegend=False 
    )
)

#Pie figure to plot pie charts
pie_fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(full_df, 
                           geojson=full_df.pie_slice, 
                           locations=full_df.index, 
                           color='region',
                           #color_continuous_scale="Cividis_r",
                           color_discrete_map=category_colors,
                           title=f"Ethnic Diversity ({sal})",
                           #mapbox_style="satellite",
                           #mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           center={"lat": y_center, "lon": x_center},
                           #zoom=custom_zoom,
                           opacity=1,
                          )
#Appending pie_fig to main fig
for trace in pie_fig.data:
    #trace.showlegend = False
    fig.add_trace(trace)
    
#Cleaning Trace legend names
clean_trace_names()
#Top 5 ethinicities in legend
append_top_sal_ethnicity()


#Annotations for pie % 
for index, row in full_df.iterrows():
    text_pos = row.orientation

    # Create a scattermapbox trace for each point
    pie_slice_text = go.Scattermapbox(
        #lat=[row.pie_slice.centroid.y],
        #lon=[row.pie_slice.centroid.x],
        lat=[row.annotation_point.y],
        lon=[row.annotation_point.x],
        mode='markers+text',
        text=[f"{row['value']:.0%}"],
        textposition=text_pos,
        textfont=dict(color='black'),
        #textfont=dict(color=category_colors.get(row.region, 'black')),
        marker=dict(size=0),
        showlegend=False,
        name="Pie Annotations"
    )
    
    # Add the trace to the figure
    fig.add_trace(pie_slice_text)


# Update layout
fig.update_layout(
    height=800, 
    width=1200,
    margin=dict(l=40, b=0),
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,0)',
    mapbox=dict(
    #bounds=dict(west=minx, east=maxx, south=miny, north=maxy) 
    ),
)

#fig.layout.mapbox.accesstoken = np.random.choice(mapbox_tokens)

# Adding a logo
fig.add_layout_image(mib_logo_temp)

#For svg legend truncation
fig.update_layout(legend=legend_font_dict)

# Show figure
#fig.show()
""
```

I have tried taking custom screenshots using a headless browser in pypupeteer by exporting map as html but there I have to add an estimate wait time. Which varies based on how much load server is under, eg. when I am doing parallel processing.
I have tried different image formats from plotly svg, png and it's common in all of them. And also tried both orca and kaleido engine.
Is there any solution?? Thanks.

This is my screenshot code.

```
async def generate_png(url, output_path):
    browser = await launch(args=['--no-sandbox'])
    page = await browser.newPage()
    #await page.setViewport({'width': 1800, 'height': 1080, 'deviceScaleFactor': 1})
    await page.emulateMedia('screen')
    await page.goto(url, waitUntil='networkidle0', timeout=60000)
    
    if run_type=="production_cache":
        await asyncio.sleep(15)

    
    # You can specify the screenshot options here
    screenshot_options = {
        'path': output_path,       # Save the screenshot to this path
        'fullPage': True,          # Capture the full scrollable page
        'omitBackground': True,    # Make the background transparent
    }
    
    await page.screenshot(screenshot_options)
    await browser.close()

import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
import nest_asyncio

ou_dir=f"output/graphics/suburb/{sal}/{typ}"
if not full_df.empty:
    fig.write_html(f'{ou_dir}/ethnicity_distribution.html', config={'displayModeBar': False})

    nest_asyncio.apply()

    async def main():
        # Using an absolute file path in the URL.
        file_path = f"{os.getcwd()}/{ou_dir}/ethnicity_distribution.html"
        url = f"file://{file_path}"
        output_path = f"{ou_dir}/ethnicity_distribution.png"

        await generate_png(url, output_path)

    
    asyncio.run(main())
```